# How to resize (height and width) of an IconButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to resize (height and width) of an IconButton in Flutter? Seems like it takes a default width and height. There is not height or width property.

```
new IconButton(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    color: themeData.primaryColor,
    icon: new Icon(Icons.clear, size: 18.0),
    onPressed: onDelete,
)
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can force it to size itself with the SizedBox.

```
SizedBox(
   height: 18.0,
   width: 18.0,
   child: IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      color: themeData.primaryColor,
      icon: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 18.0),
      onPressed: onDelete,
   )
)
```

Comment: Does this make the icon thicker or does it just increase the area of the IconButton itself? The one annoying thing about IconButton is that you can't remove the default padding.

Answer (score 52):

There is a newer way than the accepted answer. It looks like this:

```
IconButton(
  iconSize: 18.0,
  icon: new Icon(Icons.clear)
```

So use iconSize attribute and get rid of the SizedBox.

I noticed the old accepted solution had a bad drawing effect when pressing the button.

Comment: iconSize property changes only the Icon size itself, but not it's container (which is actually a SizedBox) So I assume the only way is to change the button size is to provide your own SizedBox wrapper, as the accepted answer suggests

Comment: This is incorrect. It does not change the size of the button, only the icon.

Comment: It changes the size of the button if you add it to the IconButton. I was changing the size of the Icon itself which meant much of the icon fell outside of the iconButton. Ensuring you put iconSize on the iconButton fixes this problem

Comment: Are people reading this wrong? This is obviously the most correct way to do it. People saying it's incorrect must be using the `size` attribute of the `Icon`, not the `iconSize` attribute of the `IconButton`.

Comment: its better than using sizebox

Answer (score 29):

You can replace IconButton with InkWell:

```
InkWell(
    child: Icon(Icons.clear, size: 18.0, color: themeData.primaryColor),
    onTap: onDelete,
),
```

Answer (score 26):

Use the `constraints` property on `IconButton`:

```dart
IconButton(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 36),
    icon: new Icon(Icons.clear, size: 18.0),
)
```

[Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/47457)

Answer (score 12):

If anyone's looking to change the Splash/Hover shadow size for the icon buttons. You need to set splashRadius property to the desired value in the IconButton.

```
IconButton(
     splashRadius: 12,
     padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
     icon: Icon(
             Icons.visibility,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `IconButton > splashRadius`,

```dart
IconButton(
  // use this to decrease/increase the splash spacing
  splashRadius: 24.0,  // (Material.defaultSplashRadius = 35.0)
  color: buttonColor,
  icon: Icon(Icons.heart),
  onPressed: () {},
);
```

[image: demo iconbutton]

Comment: Very underappreciated answer!

Answer (score 3):

IconButton's hit region is the area that can perceive user interaction, it has the smallest size is kMinInteractiveDimension (48.0) regardless of the actual size of the Icon.

Comment: This is part of the material guidelines which are not rules but rather good ux recommendations

Answer (score 0):

If you use images from assets folder, below should work:

```
IconButton(
      icon: Image.asset(
        "assets/images/play_3x.png",
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.white,
)
```