# How can I adjust flutter icon button (or image button) to get larger?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
leading: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => print('Menu Tapped'),
          icon: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/vecteezy_triangle_1200693.png',
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I try adding height: and width: to the Image.asset and iconsize: to IconButton but it does't work

Does it have something to do with edgeInsets?

PS* I'm quite new here, I'm follow YouTube to write a financial management app

Comment: increase the size of the button or icon of the button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize (height and width) of an IconButton in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211024/how-to-resize-height-and-width-of-an-iconbutton-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your code is about `Appbar` you need to increase the icon's space in the `Appbar` by using `toolbarHeight:` and `leadingWidth:` in the Appbar widget.
I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are providing this widget to "leading", I'm guessing this is for an AppBar. The size of the icon cannot exceed the size of your appbar. You need to increase the size of your appbar to be able to increase the size of your icon. If this doesn't work, provide your code containing the AppBar widget so I can test it out for you.